# Charge density in a conducting sphere

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, charge, conductors

We charge a conductive sphere with charge $Q$. Charges on a charged conductive sphere go towards the surface so then the **volume charge density** is 0 which makes **surface charge density** $Q$. Is my statement right?

Comment: I am not sure if you are missing something in your question, is it not obvious ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surface charge 'density' will not be Q. It will be $\sigma=\frac{3Q}{4\pi R^3}$. Yes in a conductive sphere the charges will move towards the surface, ideally speaking the volume charge density will be 0 as a result.

Comment: Your formula gives the charge/unit volume, but the charge will be distributed on the surface of a conducting sphere: ρ = Q/(4π$R^2$)